# QBFC: How do I query the customners by accountnumber?

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

Since Intuit has broken the QBFC reference today, I have to ask a question that I could normally look up.  (I do not know who to complain to).

I normally query by list_id like so:
   ICustomerQuery CustomerQueryRq = requestMsgSet.AppendCustomerQueryRq();
   CustomerQueryRq.ORCustomerListQuery.ListIDList.Add(qb_list_id);

Is there a way to query by AccountNumber?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, QuickBooks does not support querying by the AccountNumber field.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but maybe worth adding.

Create a temp "cached" object, containing all the properties you want to search for. Them when launching, and whenever customer changes are made, cache a list of custom QBcustomersForSearch objects with only the properties that you would want to use for the search.

```
class qbCustomerForSearch

property email as string
property accountnumber as string
property whatever as string
property QBListId as string

end class
```

Cache / create a list of these objects when and as needed, and search your list. Once located in your list, use the listID to identify the QB customer.

Cheers